# how can i remove a field from the manager in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

first , please try to understand my problem because i know their are too many questions related to this , but in my case no-one is working

why i dont know , please see my code .

this is working

```java
    public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener
    {
        private combine enter_in;
        private manager_s ms , ms_1 ;
        private Bitmap img;
        LabelField lb_1 , lb_2 , lb_3 ;

        public MyScreen()
        {        
            setTitle("MyTitle");

            img = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("icon.png");
            //Bitmap img_1 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("icon.png");

            enter_in = new combine ( Field.FOCUSABLE , img  );      
            enter_in.setChangeListener(this);



            ms = new manager_s( 0 , 4 );
            ms.add(enter_in);

            lb_1 = new LabelField("Menu") ;
            lb_2 = new LabelField("Favorites") ;
            lb_3 = new LabelField("Reserved") ;

            ms.add(lb_1);
            ms.add(lb_2);
            ms.add(lb_3);

            add(ms);

        }
    }
```

but when i am implementing FieldChangedListener , at that time `ms.delete(lb_1)` is not working but `delete(ms)` is working , please help solve this problem

```java
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
    {
        if ( field == enter_in )
        {
            ms.delete(lb_1);            
        }
    }
```

so , i am asking that is , there any reason for ms.delete(lb_1) not working under MyScreen class .

see this is my manager_class which i am using as , Manager ( custom_manager ) and this manager is extended by my class , for adding the fields inside the screen

```java
public class manager_s extends Manager
    {
        int col ;
        int w_1 = 20 ;

        protected manager_s(long style , int col )
        {
            super(style);
            this.col = col ;
        }
        protected void sublayout(int width, int height) 
        {

                for ( int i = 0 ; i < col ; i ++ )
                {
                    Field field = getField (i);

                    layoutChild( field , 130 , 100 );
                }

                for ( int i = 0 ; i < col ; i ++ )
                {
                    Field field = getField (i);

                    setPositionChild ( field , w_1 , 20 );

                    w_1 = w_1 + 135 ;

            setExtent ( width , 200  );
        }    
    }
}
```

and the error is **INDEX_OUT_OF_BOUND_EXCEPTION** , thats my question that , because every one on internet ( as a resource ) is saying that remove the field , but i my case nothing is working .

Comment: what is combine and manager_s ?

Comment: combine is a custom_button class , in which i am creating image button which is working fine but & combine is my manager , for it i will provide code

Comment: the problem is with your class manager_s. you creating it as ms = new manager_s( 0 , 4 ); so when you delete an item, its position removed.

Comment: when you delete one item, its col didnt changed.

Comment: so , how can i improve this mistake .

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
    setTitle("MyTitle");
    final ButtonField enter_in=new ButtonField("enter_in");
    add(enter_in);

    lb_1 = new LabelField("Menu") ;
    lb_2 = new LabelField("Favorites") ;
    lb_3 = new LabelField("Reserved") ;

    final HorizontalFieldManager ms=new HorizontalFieldManager();
    ms.add(lb_1);
    lb_1.setMargin(0,50,0,0);//Here you can set the spacing between the Fields.
    ms.add(lb_2);
    lb_2.setMargin(0,50,0,0);//Here you can set the spacing between the Fields.
    ms.add(lb_3);

    add(ms);

    FieldChangeListener listener=new FieldChangeListener() {

        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        if(field==enter_in){
            ms.delete(lb_1);
            ms.invalidate();

        }
        }
    };
    enter_in.setChangeListener(listener);
```

In place of my ButtonField , you can use your combine.